# I've flagged to remove a warning template, and haven't received a response. Should I panic?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

This [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/400069/1420) was posted on July 15, received a warning template on July 19, was edited on July 20, and I flagged it to have the warning template removed on the same day, and haven't (as of July 28) received a response - the flag is still marked as "Pending".

Is the sword of Damocles still hovering over this answer? Is it likely to be deleted before I get a response to my flag?

Comment: I'd say no: "**Notice removed** Insufficient explanation by tchrist♦ occurred 1 hour ago"